# Inner join tables with 2 preferences

Tags: mysql, inner-join

```
SELECT a.num, a.status, a.name, b.time 
FROM a inner join b on a.num = b.num 
WHERE a.name = "a";
```

I would want to join two tables (table a and table b) together. I managed to run the code above but no values were displayed though i have added values in table a.

Sample output of table a:

```
Num Status     Name 
 1   available  a
```

Table b:

```
bNum Time  Num
1     9:00  1
```

Comment: post your sample input too.

Comment: This mean that your a.num = b.num don't match or a.name="a"  don't match .. show you sample data

Comment: edited, this is the sample data. It still doesnt display anything

Comment: what is the data type of num column in both tables? is it the same?

Answer (score 0):

Could be you have some other char in name  (space or similar) 
   try

```
SELECT a.num, a.status, a.name, b.time 
FROM a inner join b on a.num = b.num 
WHERE a.name like '%a%';
```

or you have a cast problem with num column

```
SELECT a.num, a.status, a.name, b.time 
FROM a inner join b on cast(a.num  as unsigned) = cast(b.num  as unsigned)
WHERE a.name like '%a%';
```